# Is JSON type in PostgreSQL part of transactions?

Tags: json, postgresql, transactions, postgresql-9.3

Just want to know if JSON type is also comes under the transactions. For e.g. If I have started a transaction which insert data both for column JSON types and others and if something wrong happens, will it rollback the json stuff as well?

Comment: Yes of course it is. Why do you think it wouldn't be ?

Comment: As in NoSql DB's like MongoDB transactions are not supported, we are about to start with postgreSql very first time. I couldn't find exact written somewhere if above thing is true, so I asked. Anyways thanks for confirming.

Comment: Well Postgres isn't a "NoSQL" database, it is an ACID compliant SQL database which happens to support some NoSQL data types that break the _relational_ concept, but not the ACID principle.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

*Everything* is transactional and crash-safe in PostgreSQL unless explicitly documented not to be.

PostgreSQL's transactions operate on *tuples*, not individual fields. The data type is irrelevant. It isn't really possible to implement a data type that is *not* transactional in PostgreSQL. (The `SERIAL` "data type" is just a wrapper for the `integer` type with a `DEFAULT`, and is a bit of a special case).

Only a few things have special behaviour regarding transactions - sequences, advisory locks, etc - and they're pretty clearly documented where that's the case.

Note that this imposes some limitations you may not immediately expect. Most importantly, [because PostgreSQL relies on MVCC for concurrency control](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/mvcc.html) it must *copy* a value when that value is modified (or, sometimes, when other values in the same tuple are modified). It cannot change fields in-place. So if you have a 5MB `json` document in a field and you change a single integer value, *the whole json document must be copied and written out with the changed value*. PostgreSQL will then come along later and mark the old copy as free space that can be re-used.